# Bigcommerce app - How to change the Auth Callback URL

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I am new to Bigcommerce app

From the sample github,
https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex

How to give the

Auth Callback URL: `https://<app hostname>/bigcommerce/callback`

Load Callback URL: `https://<app hostname>/bigcommerce/load`

Uninstall Callback URL: `https://<app hostname>/bigcommerce/uninstall`

where,
`<app hostname>` represent 
`http://localhost/repo/hello-world-app-php-silex` (or)

```
http://XXX.mybigcommerce.com/hello-world-app-php-silex
```

In the point 5,
they mentioned as "Restart the software or the entire host as needed to set the environment variables." How to restart ?

Comment: It just means if you had the server/localhost running, to reinitiate the process and verify the new variables are being used.

Comment: please kindly share the code format of the bigcommerce app beacause i am new bigcommerce app development.

Comment: have you looked at https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex/?

Comment: please check my question properly i checked with this github example only

Answer (score 0):

When you add the Auth Call back URL's to your .env file as per the example. You need to restart the web server. That is the point mentioned on the GitHub page.

```
 BC_AUTH_SERVICE=https://login.bigcommerce.com
 BC_CLIENT_ID=<contents of Client ID field>
 BC_CLIENT_SECRET=<contents of Client Secret field>
 BC_CALLBACK_URL=<URL TO YOUR AUTH CALLBACK ENDPOINT>
```

Also, note that the `BC_CALLBACK_URL` has to be the same you setup in developer portal when you configure the app.

[image]

Comment: please kindly check my early comments and give your reply i am asking code file format of the to develop bigcommerce app.